# matrix-vector multiple vs. dgemm

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, intel-mkl

I'm doing a large number of matrix-vector multiply's in my code. I found that my naive implementation beats cblas_dgemm in MKL10. My own guess why this might be the case is dgemm does alpha*A *B + beta *C whereas I'm only doing A*B. But the naive implementation is significantly better (~3x speedup). Any thoughts why this might be the case?

Here is the matrix-vector-mult implementation:

```
void mat_vec_mul(double *a, double *b, double *c, int m, int k)
{

    for (int ii = 0; ii < m; ii++){
        for (int kk = 0; kk < k; kk++){
            *c += *(a+ii*k+kk) * *(b+ii);       

        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ow! Warning: Horrendous buffer overflows and other unsafety detected!

Comment: What are the sizes of the matrices ? Can you also provide the exact code used for your benchmark, since one ill-placed transposition could mean much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've benchmarked the code. But why not try doing the multiplication in the same way as DGEMM?

You've already stated that DGEMM does alpha * A * B + beta * C, so why not try writing that too and see how it compares with DGEMM.

You'll probably find it's as fast (or slower) than DGEMM. You're doing a lot less operations, which is most likely the reason why it's faster.

Comment: Well "beta" is always set to 0 when dgemm is called. So if i were to implement alpha * A * B + beta * C, I'd check if beta is ~0 so I'm essentially doing alpha * A * B without extra operations.

Answer (score 0):

The original blas routine http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgemm.f contains a number of if statements that test for the value of beta. I guess that is already generating some overhead in the performance. I wonder what would happen if you took the original dgemm routine and specialized it to the case that you're considering. Furthermore, it would be nice to see a comparison depending on the matrix size.